# Grouping Nearby Contours/Bounding Rectangles

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an image containing obscure rectangular shapes:
[image]

Using opencv I would like to group nearby rectangles to have an expected output as:
[image]

I've used the Dilate Morphological Transformation to enlarge the shapes so that they would be joined to create a larger shape which produces:
[image]

It doesn't join the larger rectangles to right very well, with a kernel size (40,40) any larger the smaller rectangles join to be one big one instead of separates.

Possible to use cv2.minAreaRect(c) and group by similar angles of the rectangles? or any feature based detection in getting the number of rectangles in a certain area?

Comment: A thin vertical kernel should do what you want. Just make it taller than the maximum of the minimum gaps over all objects you want to connect.

Comment: @fmw42 thanks, a vertical kernel works better, but it makes those vertical rectangles on the left taller and joins that column into one as well. Could a erosion after separate them?

Comment: See my answer below. You need to use morphology close to avoid the lengthening.

Answer (score 2):

A thin vertical kernel should do what you want. Just make it taller than the maximum of the minimum 1/2 gaps over all objects you want to connect. Looks like about 65 pixels should work. Here is the morphology close result in Python/OpenCV that seems to connect the parts you want.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lines.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# threshold to binary
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[2]

# apply morphology 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,65))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# write results
cv2.imwrite("lines_morphology.png", morph)

# show results
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morph", morph)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for with the rectangles on the right side. Is it possible to set it so this left side https://imgur.com/a/vMXZjDl doesn't join as one?

Comment: Not likely. It depends upon which grouping has the larger gaps that need to be filled to connect them. Measure and see which is larger. I think the cluster on the far right is larger. So to connect them, you need a larger kernel than for that group..

Comment: You need a kernel that is slightly larger than the largest gap that needs to be filled in order to join all components. Anything with a smaller gap will be connected and anything with a larger gap will remain disconnected.